# Excluding an undefined value

Tags: javascript

Every once in a while I will see an `<li>undefined</li>`    How do i get it to not loop over the undefined `<li>`?

```
function relatedCoursesMesh() {
    if ($('#relatedCourses').length != 0) {
        var courseNumber = $.parseHTML($('#relatedCourses #RelatedCourseNumber').html()),
            courseName = $.parseHTML($('#relatedCourses #RelatedCourseName').html()),
            parsedCourseNumber = courseNumber[0].data.split("+"),
            parsedCourseName = courseName[0].data.split("+");


        htmlOutput = "<ul>";

        $(parsedCourseNumber).each(function (index, val) {

            htmlOutput += '<li><a data-course="' + val + '" data-title="' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" href="/Pages/Class.aspx?course=' + val + '&courseTitle=' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" title="Related Course">' + parsedCourseName[index] + '</a></li>';
        })
        htmlOutput += "</ul>";
        $('#relatedCourses').html(htmlOutput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't throw error messages in most cases when you use undefined.

Comment: We'd need to see how you're putting your data into your variable(s) to see why sometimes it comes up with `undefined`. Please edit your question with this info.

Comment: Try filtering the list for empty values before iterating with the forEach. So theList.filter((it)=>!!it).forEach(()=>{Your logic})

Comment: I don't see any way that this could result in `undefined`. The array that `split()` returns can never contain undefined values.

Comment: It also can't produce `<li>undefined</li>` because it always has `<a ...></a>` around the array data.

Comment: Why are you using `$.parseHTML(something.html())`? Just use `courseNumber = $("#relatedCourses #RelatedCourseNumber")`. Getting the HTML and parsing it just result in the same DOM elements.

Comment: As suggested, we really need to see how the data is being stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an `if` statement like so:

```
    $(parsedCourseNumber).each(function (index, val) {
        if(parsedCourseName[index]) { // also ignores "" (blank) and null values
            htmlOutput += '<li><a data-course="' + val + '" data-title="' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" href="/Pages/Class.aspx?course=' + val + '&courseTitle=' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" title="Related Course">' + parsedCourseName[index] + '</a></li>';
        }
    })
```

Comment: I'd be more concerned as to why the data is "faulty" rather than pretending it isn't

Comment: What's interesting is I think Barmar's comment makes this answer invalid, because perhaps `parsedCourseName[index]` is actually "undefined" from something previous, ha.

Comment: We may not have the entire actual code. I wouldn't assume that `parsedCourseName[index]` can't legally be null or blank. Make the `if` statement more explicit: `if(parsedCourseName[index] !== undefined)`

Comment: @LeeTaylor yep, you're preaching to the choir here.

Comment: @LeeTaylor  I'm new to this.  Why is it faulty?

Comment: @Wendy take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null#Difference_between_null_and_undefined to see what they're talking about

Comment: @AlvinThompson So, I wouldn't recommend an answer that advocates ignoring a fundamental of Computer Science...

Comment: Lets play nicely kids

Comment: @LeeTaylor I've worked in a lot of big teams before, and not all developers are created equal. Sometimes the data you're handed is crap and the best you can do is slap a Band-Aid on it.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Yes, I know. But I believe that Wendy is in control of her own data. As such, wise to get that part correct to start with.

Comment: I hope the extended discussion on this is particularly helpful for Wendy.

Comment: @CodyG. I actually appreciate the banter.  I was given this code to keep running until this site is moved to a new system.

Comment: Well, there's plenty of people watching this question if you want to dive deep into making it better!

Comment: @AlvinThompson yes. I was given this code and asked to keep it going until the site is moved to a new system.  It has been "band aided" for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can control if the value of `val` variable return as undefined, so:

```js
function relatedCoursesMesh() {
    if ($('#relatedCourses').length != 0) {
        var courseNumber = $.parseHTML($('#relatedCourses #RelatedCourseNumber').html()),
            courseName = $.parseHTML($('#relatedCourses #RelatedCourseName').html()),
            parsedCourseNumber = courseNumber[0].data.split("+"),
            parsedCourseName = courseName[0].data.split("+");


        htmlOutput = "<ul>";

        $(parsedCourseNumber).each(function (index, val) {
            if(val !== undefined && parsedCourseName[index] !== undefined) {
              htmlOutput += '<li><a data-course="' + val + '" data-title="' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" href="/Pages/Class.aspx?course=' + val + '&courseTitle=' + parsedCourseName[index] + '" title="Related Course">' + parsedCourseName[index] + '</a></li>';
            }
        });
        htmlOutput += "</ul>";
        return $('#relatedCourses').html(htmlOutput);
    }
}
```

Being a function it would be better to return the value of the operation performed:

`return $('#relatedCourses').html(htmlOutput);`.

But surely the best way is to see why the data is originally defective.

Comment: This is the equivalent of putting a sticker over your car's oil warning light. Better to see why the data is faulty in the first place. Otherwise other problems will rear their heads later.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but with the little information we have available this is the only possible solution.